# how to fix browser unexpectedly closed error when using requests_html on aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests-html

I'm running requests_html on python 3.10 on aws lambda with a 3000 memory and 10000 emphemeral storage
when it tries to run something it gives the error browser closed unexpectedly
Using a layer for requests_html made from docker, just the basic way to package a library for aws

here is my code

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    filename = event['userid']
    url = event['url']
    headers = {'user-agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
    links = set()
    session = HTMLSession()  
    response = session.get(url,headers=headers)
    response.html.render(scrolldown=10000)
    for element in response.html.find("a.hfpxzc"):
        links.add(element.attrs['href'])
    return{
        "body": links
    }
```

here is the logs

```
START RequestId: fbd957ca-dffc-495c-b946-6e1c6fedefe0 Version: $LATEST
[INFO] Starting Chromium download.
[INFO]  2023-04-19T17:51:17.489Z    fbd957ca-dffc-495c-b946-6e1c6fedefe0    Starting Chromium download.
0%|          | 0.00/109M [00:00<?, ?b/s]
  1%|          | 993k/109M [00:00<00:10, 9.90Mb/s]
 12%|█▏        | 13.2M/109M [00:00<00:01, 75.7Mb/s]
 23%|██▎       | 25.0M/109M [00:00<00:00, 95.0Mb/s]
 32%|███▏      | 34.5M/109M [00:00<00:00, 91.3Mb/s]
 40%|████      | 43.7M/109M [00:00<00:00, 85.3Mb/s]
 52%|█████▏    | 56.1M/109M [00:00<00:00, 97.1Mb/s]
 64%|██████▎   | 69.2M/109M [00:00<00:00, 107Mb/s] 
 75%|███████▌  | 81.8M/109M [00:00<00:00, 113Mb/s]
 86%|████████▌ | 93.3M/109M [00:00<00:00, 105Mb/s]
 97%|█████████▋| 106M/109M [00:01<00:00, 110Mb/s] 
100%|██████████| 109M/109M [00:01<00:00, 100Mb/s]
[INFO] Beginning extraction
[INFO]  2023-04-19T17:51:18.720Z    fbd957ca-dffc-495c-b946-6e1c6fedefe0    Beginning extraction
[INFO] Chromium extracted to: /tmp/local-chromium/588429
[INFO]  2023-04-19T17:51:20.808Z    fbd957ca-dffc-495c-b946-6e1c6fedefe0    Chromium extracted to: /tmp/local-chromium/588429
[ERROR] BrowserError: Browser closed unexpectedly:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 12, in lambda_handler
    response.html.render(scrolldown=10000)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 587, in render
    self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 731, in browser
    self._browser = self.loop.run_until_complete(super().browser)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 715, in browser
    self._browser = await pyppeteer.launch(ignoreHTTPSErrors=not(self.verify), headless=True, args=self.__browser_args)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 307, in launch
    return await Launcher(options, **kwargs).launch()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 168, in launch
    self.browserWSEndpoint = get_ws_endpoint(self.url)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 227, in get_ws_endpoint
    raise BrowserError('Browser closed unexpectedly:\n')END RequestId: fbd957ca-dffc-495c-b946-6e1c6fedefe0
REPORT RequestId: fbd957ca-dffc-495c-b946-6e1c6fedefe0  Duration: 34358.77 ms   Billed Duration: 34359 ms   Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 488 MB Init Duration: 695.64 ms
```

tried looking at fixes for pyppeteer as I think it is the issue and I edited my requests_html layer to try and add the no sandbox argument but it didn't work.

Would switching to using a different language or technology be a better idea? Or is there a way to fix this?
Any help is greatly appreciated